# How to write aync method in the .netcore3.0 web api

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to write async method for following method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("PhysicianNPIsandAttestedCount")]
public  ActionResult PhysicianNPIsandAttestedCount()
{
    var adminGrid =  GetPhysicianDetailsForAdminHome();
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adminGrid));
}
```

can any one help me?

Comment: Is `GetPhysicianDetailsForAdminHome()` an async method? Thats why you need to call it in an other asnc method?

Comment: I have a problem at "return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adminGrid));" if write async to 
}PhysicianNPIsandAttestedCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming `GetPhysicianDetailsForAdminHome` is async.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("PhysicianNPIsandAttestedCount")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PhysicianNPIsandAttestedCount()
{
    try 
    {
      var adminGrid =  await GetPhysicianDetailsForAdminHome();
      if( adminGrid == null )
        return NotFound();
      return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(adminGrid));
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
       // do some logging here...
    }
    return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error. Somthing went Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: How can I return  other status codes instead of OK ?

Comment: Some are builtin, others you have to do manually. I will updated my answer.

Comment: Now I am getting error at return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error. Something went Wrong!"); How can write without statuscode() method?

Comment: What error are you getting? and i dont understand your question?